# SSRS: Category groups randomly changing order

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a few column charts in a ssrs report. The x-axis (categories) are the past 6 months. There is no ordering on the chart - I do all that in the SQL query and just want them to display in the order of the query.

It usually does this, i.e. in order:
**Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct**

However sometimes it will display:
**Oct, Apr, May, Sep, Jun, Jul, Aug**

After a little while it will jump back to how it should be.
Does anyone have any insight into why it would suddenly change?

The report is not filtered by anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort the category group by. In the chart data options select the dropdown for the category group and go to `Category Group Properties`.

On the left-hand side you'll see a section called "Sorting". Add your date column to the sorting and it should always be sorted correctly.

Alternatively you can use an ORDER BY in your query to ensure you get the rows in the correct order. However if you're grouping and aggregating rows in the chart I'm not 100% sure if the behaviour will hold up.

Even if you return Jan,Feb, etc you could use a SWITCH() statement to get the correct order but that would be painful. Better to return a column with a number or date in it to allow you to make sure you order the chart correctly.

Comment: The thing is, in this case I am bringing back "Jan", "Feb" etc, not the date. My boss is a fan of formatting everything in SQL first. I could change the query - but since this works most of the time it seems a bit silly.

Comment: I'm a fan of doing most things in SQL but formatting text is somethign that SSRS is quite good at. But, can't do much about bosses as you can about code. You say it works most of the time but that is due to sheer luck of the result set SQL decides to give you. If you use an ORDER BY in your query you can be sure of the order of the results and do everything in SQL to make your boss happy.

Comment: I agree, not a huge fan of SSRS but it does format text well! I will add in an extra ORDER BY although not sure how sql is changing the results around... If it never does it again then I will know! Thanks for the input.

Comment: Even if a result set appears to be ordered correctly without an ORDER BY you cannot guarantee the order. That is just how SQL works. Something about how it pulls the rows from the table changed occasionally and would mess up your order. (Perhaps row locks or something, but I'm totally just guessing.)